# Problemas al momento de trabajar en el modelo django el error que me da es (TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple))

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

He intentado varias cosas para poder solucionar esto tanto el .format que busque dentro de otras preguntas pero aun no logro solucionarlo asique ya despues de recorrer todo lo que entendi no encontre mas que hacer esto sucede cuando entro a la pagina de admin y apreto para agregar al Horas_medica

```
class Horas_medica(models.Model):
   id_boxes = models.ForeignKey(Boxe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   id_medico = models.ForeignKey(Medico, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   id_paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   descripcion = models.TextField()
   diagnostico = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
           default=timezone.now)
     
   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)
```

y la consola me devuelve TypeError: str returned non-string (type tuple)

Comment: lo que estas intentando es obtener el id del modelo en string si es asi lo que tienes que hacer es str(self.pk) recuerda que el modelo se identifica por medio de la pk

Comment: @cosmosmulti te refieres a algo como tener el id asi? 
`
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
`
Poniendo esto antes de id_boxes?

Comment: Mira lo que esta pasando es que estas redornando en eletodo __str__ el ID del modelo pero lo estas convirtiendo en string, por eso te da el error lo que tienes que hacer es __str__(self):return str(self.pk), y ya con ese tendrás el ID del modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ayudaron en el Foro en ingles y quería compartir la respuesta de este problema con ustedes en caso de que no sepan mucho ingles
El problema realmente no estaba en lo que puse luego de hablar con los chicos y compartir todo el codigo con respecto encontramos que el problema estaba dentro del models pero no especificamente en ese extracto de codigo sino que estaba en Paciente y Medico los cuales estaban asi de un inicio

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos


class Medico(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    contrasena = models.TextField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos
```

y para solucionar el problema lo dejamos así lo cual ya quito todos los errores que se me producían

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)


class Medico(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField()
    apellidos = models.TextField()
    rut = models.TextField()
    contrasena = models.TextField()
    direccion = models.TextField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.rut, self.nombre, self.apellidos)
```

Muchas gracias igualmente a los que intentaron responder mi problema <3